# Laravel Error on Production on HasApiToken

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new on laravel and I have created a basic dashboard with the api endpoints. Everything works fine on Localhost , but when I have hosted it on the server I get an error saying

Class Laravel\Passport\HasAPITokens; not found on User.php

Here s what my user.php looks like

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasAPITokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
?>
```

Also the api endpoint also stopped working saying the Controller class I have created is not found.

I have followed the steps to publish here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4&t=557s

Comment: did you put your laravel app in some folders under `public_html` ?

Comment: no , I put the public folder in public_html  and the other files in other folder created under home folder. I changed the index.php in public_html to point that folder

Comment: So any of your request is reaching to your controller or not?

Comment: if I remove HasApiTokens from user , the website and pages starts loading. But the API endpoints is not working . the error says controller not found

Comment: ok @stacy give gayatri darade's answer a try.

Comment: Are you developing on Windows and uploading to Linux, by any chance? It looks like you're developing on a case-insensitive filesystem and uploading to a case-sensitive one. The answer given below is a bit light on explanation, but it should fix the issue.

Comment: @iainn yes , my operating system is Windows and the Shared Hosting account has Linux

Answer (score 5):

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

Comment: Thanks , this worked . @iainn thanks for the explanation